# Packages that can be installed with gradle

Tags: android

I am new to Android. As I wanted to make a bottom navigation view, I found a youtube video explaining how to do it :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPV8xA7m-iw

So he says that for the import steps, I have to :

1) add the following line in the app:build.gradle file
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

2) add the following line in the main activity source file
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Everything works fine, however there is something I don't understand concerning the internet documentation of this class.
I found the class documentation with google :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

but when I follow the path from the root of the android documentation, I am stuck there :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/package-summary

and I don't find the class BottomNavigationView listed in the package (which I should, right ?).
Is this a hole in the android documentation, or is it normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andorid studio has couple of template apps. Select Bottom Navigation Activity, there you can see how it works.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But appart from making it work, do you know why the class BottomNavigationView isn't listed in
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/package-summary  ?